# XSL-FO combining two lines from different nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I would appreciate some input and help with the problem I have with XML and FOP.

From this xml:

```
 <selectedcalculation>
   <CLASSXml>
     <CalcData>
       <SpareParts>
         <PartDtls>
           <PartDtl>
             <RepTyp>E</RepTyp>
             <GId>0281</GId>
             <PartDesc>FRONT BUMPER</PartDesc>
             <PartNo>16 107 424 80</PartNo>
             <Price Cur="HRK">+2496.37</Price>
           </PartDtl>
           <PartDtl>
             <RepTyp>E</RepTyp>
             <GId>0471</GId>
             <PartDesc>HOOD</PartDesc>
             <PartNo>98 021 631 80</PartNo>
             <Price Cur="HRK">+2273.92</Price>
           </PartDtl>
           <PartDtl>
             <RepTyp>E</RepTyp>
             <GId>0561</GId>
             <PartDesc>LEFT HEADLIGHT</PartDesc>
             <PartNo>16 180 003 80</PartNo>
             <Price Cur="HRK">+4756.61</Price>
           </PartDtl>
           <PartDtl>
             <RepTyp>E</RepTyp>
             <GId>0741</GId>
             <PartDesc>LEFT FRONT FENDER</PartDesc>
             <PartNo>98 021 643 80</PartNo>
             <Price Cur="HRK">+1162.04</Price>
           </PartDtl>
         </PartDtls>
       </SpareParts>
     </CalcData>
   </CLASSXml>
   <repairCaptureData>
     <Capoeira>
       <RepairData>
         <RepairPartList>
           <ClassicRepairPartBasic>
             <GuideNumber number="0471" type="Unspecified"/>
             <RepairInfoList>
               <ClassicRepairInfoSPVehicle>
                 <RepairMethod>E</RepairMethod>
                 <Comment>Installation control</Comment>
               </ClassicRepairInfoSPVehicle>
             </RepairInfoList>
           </ClassicRepairPartBasic>
           <ClassicRepairPartBasic>
             <GuideNumber number="0281" type="Unspecified"/>
             <RepairInfoList>
               <ClassicRepairInfoSPVehicle>
                 <RepairMethod>E</RepairMethod>
               </ClassicRepairInfoSPVehicle>
             </RepairInfoList>
           </ClassicRepairPartBasic>
           <ClassicRepairPartBasic>
             <GuideNumber number="0561" type="Unspecified"/>
             <RepairInfoList>
               <ClassicRepairInfoSPVehicle>
                 <RepairMethod>E</RepairMethod>
               </ClassicRepairInfoSPVehicle>
             </RepairInfoList>
           </ClassicRepairPartBasic>
           <ClassicRepairPartBasic>
             <GuideNumber number="0741" type="Unspecified"/>
             <RepairInfoList>
               <ClassicRepairInfoSPVehicle>
                 <RepairMethod>E</RepairMethod>
                 <Comment>Return to insurance</Comment>
               </ClassicRepairInfoSPVehicle>
             </RepairInfoList>
           </ClassicRepairPartBasic>
         </RepairPartList>
       </RepairData>
     </Capoeira>
   </repairCaptureData>
 </selectedcalculation>
```

How can I combine from one node to read **PartDesc** and from another to read **Comment** to get something like this:

1. FRONT BUMBER
2. HOOD Installation control
3. LEFT HEADLIGHT
4. LEFT FRONT FENDER Return to insurance

I guess this need to be used **GId 0281 GId** and **GuideNumber number="0281" type="Unspecified"** but I don't know how.

I'm using this xsl-fo now:

```
 <fo:block>
   <xsl:if test="count(//CalcData[RunDesc='NormalCalc']/SpareParts/PartDtls/PartDtl)>0">
     <xsl:for-each select="//CLASSXml/CalcData[RunDesc='NormalCalc']/SpareParts/PartDtls/PartDtl
    [((Price/@Cur = 'HRK') or (Price/@Cur = 'EUR'))]">
    <xsl:variable name="MyGId" select="GId"/>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:if test="//CalcData[RunDesc='NormalCalc']/SpareParts/PartDtls/PartDtl/Price/@Cur = 'HRK' or //CalcData[RunDesc='NormalCalc']/SpareParts/PartDtls/PartDtl/Price/@Cur = 'EUR' or //CalcData[RunDesc='NormalCalc']/SpareParts/PartDtls/PartDtl/Price/@Cur = 'RSD'"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="'. '"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="PartDesc"/>   
         </xsl:if>
       </fo:block> 
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:if> 
 </fo:block>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should just navigate on your XML tree. Get the node RepairInfoList preceding sibling of the GuideNumber which have the GId value. Use the XPath with the revelant predicats:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::selectedcalculation/repairCaptureData/descendant::RepairInfoList[preceding-sibling::GuideNumber[@number = $MyGId]]/ClassicRepairInfoSPVehicle/Comment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  `xsl:key` and the `key()` function are useful for doing lookups in other parts of the document.  `fo:list-block` and related FOs are designed for making lists.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e12374.  Lastly, breaking things into multiple `xsl:template` lets the structure of the document dictate what happens, makes XPaths shorter, and, I find, makes templates that are shorter and easier to understand.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="PartDtl" match="PartDtl" use="GId" />

    <xsl:template match="selectedcalculation">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="spm">
                    <fo:region-body />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="repairCaptureData" />
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RepairPartList">
        <fo:list-block>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ClassicRepairPartBasic">
                <xsl:sort select="key('PartDtl', GuideNumber/@number)/PartDesc" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ClassicRepairPartBasic">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('PartDtl', GuideNumber/@number)/PartDesc" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="RepairInfoList/ClassicRepairInfoSPVehicle/Comment"
                     />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Comment">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This also works, I will have to implement it to my code and see what works best. Thanks!